# Iterating through cells in a table

Tags: php, html-table

I'm having some trouble with a table I'm trying to create.
I want the individual cells to have different colors depending on the date.

This is part of the code:

```
$linecolor = '#dddddd';
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($mon_date . "- 7 days"));
$datecell = $date;
do {
    $calender.='<TR>
                     <TD class="hand" width="20" BGCOLOR="' . $art['color'] . '" title="' . $art['longname'] . '" align=left>' . $art['shortname'] . '</TD>
                     <TD class="hand" width="225" BGCOLOR="' . $linecolor . '" title="' . $art['art_text'] . '" align=left>' . $art['art'] . '</TD>
                     <TD width="50" BGCOLOR="' . $linecolor . '" align="left">' . $art['artnr'] . '</TD>';
    $num=1;
    $count = 7;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (strtotime($today_date) > strtotime($datecell)) {

            $calender .= '<TD class="hand" width="65" BGCOLOR="#888888" title="Booking Guard!">'.$num.'</TD>
                          <TD class="hand" width="65" BGCOLOR="#888888" title="Booking Guard!">'.$num.'</TD>';

        }
        elseif (strtotime($today_date) == strtotime($datecell) || strtotime($today_date) < strtotime($datecell) ) {
            $calender .= '<TD class="hand" width="65" BGCOLOR="' . $linecolor . '" title="Book item">'.$num.'</TD>
                           <TD class="hand" width="65" BGCOLOR="' . $linecolor . '" title="Book item">'.$num.'</TD>';
        }

        $datecell=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($datecell . "+1 days"));
        $num++;
    }

    if ($linecolor == '#dddddd') {
        $linecolor = '#eeeeee';
    } elseif ($linecolor == '#eeeeee') {
        $linecolor = '#dddddd';
    }

} while ($art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

It's currently looking something like this:

[image: Table_problem]

What I don't understand is why the numbers are written out in columns but not my darker grey cell colors.

Any helpful tips would be appreciated

**Edit**

`$today_date` is today's date, and `$mon_date` is the Monday of the selected week

For example, now its Tuesday, so I would like Monday to be grayed out.

Comment: You can combine `x == y || x < y` into `x <= y`.

Comment: Although you don't even need that test, because if it's in the `else` of `if (x > y)` then it has to be `(x <= y)`.

Comment: Apply CSS classes, not in-line CSS.

Comment: What is `$today_date`? Could you explain which cells are supposed to get which colors?